# Formatting JSON for bulk Keen.io upload

Tags: ruby, json, keen-io

I am trying to setup a sample bulk upload to Keen.io using the ruby gem.  From their docs:

```
Keen.publish_batch(
  :signups => [
    { :name => "Bob" },
    { :name => "Mary" }
  ],
  :purchases => [
    { :price => 10 },
    { :price => 20 }
  ]
)
```

My attempt at a rake task to generate something similar:

```
task backfill_keen_jobs: :environment do

   jobs_array = Array.new
   Job.last(5).each do |j|
      job_type = j.job_type.present? ? j.job_type.description : nil
      job = {
         :keen => {
            :timestamp => j.created_at.to_time.iso8601
         },
         :id => j.id,
         :title => j.title,
         :type => job_type,
         :company => j.company

      }

      jobs_array << JSON.generate(job)

   end
   puts jobs_array
   puts Keen.publish_batch(:jobs => [jobs_array.to_json])
end
```

I get the following error:

`{"jobs"=>[{"success"=>false, "error"=>{"name"=>"InvalidPropertyNameError", "description"=>"An event should be a JSON object of properties."}}]}`

I am sure I am just messing up the JSON output somehow, but I can't seem to figure out how/where?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This should work if you do not call .to_json on the array that you have created.

Try,

`Keen.publish_batch(:jobs => jobs_array)`

as opposed to what is currently stated

`Keen.publish_batch(:jobs => [jobs_array.to_json])`

Hope this helps!

Comment: I made that change and get `{"jobs"=>[{"success"=>false, "error"=>{"name"=>"InvalidPropertyNameError", "description"=>"An event should be a JSON object of properties."}}

Comment: Try removing everything about JSON. jobs_array should just have Hashes pushed into it, and publish_batch does not need the to_json in it.

Comment: thanks @Elof that pretty much did it!  I just needed to drop the bracket as well.  Full code in the answer in case it helps anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer in case it helps anyone else....

```
   jobs_array = Array.new
   Job.last(5).each do |j|
      job_type = j.job_type.present? ? j.job_type.description : nil
      job = {
         :keen => {
            :timestamp => j.created_at.to_time.iso8601
         },
         :id => j.id.to_i,
         :title => j.title,
         :type => job_type,
         :company => j.company
      }

      jobs_array << job

   end
   jobs_array
   Keen.publish_batch(:jobs => jobs_array)
```